# Nextcloud docker - issue to define https

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

i am trying to install nextcloud docker with reverse proxy the log in should be defined with SSO in Active directory.
after setting everything up , i noticed that the request are sent from the docker are in HTTP format and not in HTTPS format (due to implementing certificates).

this is the docker compose i am running:

```
"version: "3"
volumes:
  nextcloud-data:
  nextcloud-db:
  npm-data:
  npm-ssl:
  npm-db:

networks:
  frontend:
    # add this if the network is already existing!
    # external: true
  backend:

services:
  nextcloud-app:
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-data:/var/www/html
      - /home/admin-1/nextcloud:/var/www
      - ./config:/var/www/html/config:rw

      
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=##
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=nextcloud-db
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend


  nextcloud-db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=##
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=##
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
    networks:
      - backend

  npm-app:
    image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "81:81"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - DB_MYSQL_HOST=npm-db
      - DB_MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - DB_MYSQL_USER=npm
      - DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD=##
      - DB_MYSQL_NAME=npm
    volumes:
      - npm-data:/data
      - npm-ssl:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  npm-db:
    image: jc21/mariadb-aria:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=##
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=npm
      - MYSQL_USER=npm
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=##
    volumes:
      - npm-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
```

this is the config.php file that i pulled form the docker container and modified according to the form guide online.

```
<?php
$CONFIG = array (
  'htaccess.RewriteBase' => '/',
  'memcache.local' => '\\OC\\Memcache\\APCu',
  'apps_paths' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/apps',
      'url' => '/apps',
      'writable' => false,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'path' => '/var/www/html/custom_apps',
      'url' => '/custom_apps',
      'writable' => true,
    ),
  ),
  'instanceid' => 'oc6n8toieebi',
  'passwordsalt' => 'BH6p+QxYGiA8RU2PIygTIB+9UMC3nP',
  'secret' => 'JG0qIDzWIUjyBVkKsuPg0Ku97tUAnOn1kzwroU4GrRnpsCLY',
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'nextcloud.domain',
  ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/www/html/data',
  'dbtype' => 'mysql',
  'version' => '26.0.2.1',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://nextcloud.domain',
  'dbname' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbhost' => 'nextcloud-db',
  'dbport' => '',
  'dbtableprefix' => 'oc_',
  'mysql.utf8mb4' => true,
  'dbuser' => 'nextcloud',
  'dbpassword' => '###',
  'installed' => true,
);
```

the error i am getting is "Configuration was not read or initialized correctly in the config.php file "